# AngularJS GET petition in a Factory

Tags: angularjs, ajax, get

I've seen several posts about this, but I cannot adapt them to what I want to do.

I have a GET petition to a server to get a JSON response, and works like a charm.

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
       $scope.elements = data;
    });
}])
```

Now I can print in the view with ng-repeat, all the elements within $scope.elements.

But now I need to do two different GETs, depending if has Internet, check online, if has not, check local DB.

I've created a factory like follows:

```
.factory('AttemptFactory', function($http){

var self = this;

this.elements = [];

this.returnFunction = function() {

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        self.elements = data;
     });
 }
}
```

I've firstly tried to fill this.elements, and then in the first controller access to it with $scope.newList =  = AttemptFactory.elements.
Also tried make a return self.elements, and receive it with a  AttemptFactory = AttemptFactory.returnFunction ();

I added the dependency injection of AttemptFactory to the .controller().

How can I archieve it??

if (online) 
   data = Get(from_server);
else
   data = Get(from_local_DB);

return data;

Something like this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try separating your concerns a bit. I'd recommend creating two factories: one that interacts with your server and one that interacts with the local db. Each could have a method that fetches data from the respective data store and returns a Promise for that data.

Then in your controller, you can choose which function to call based on the connection status. The function calls will both return a Promise that you can `.then` off of to get the data for your view. For example:

```
.factory('ServerFactory', function($http){

    var serverFactory = {};

    serverFactory.fetchJson = function() {
        // note that we're returning the promise that $http get returns that will resolve with our data
        return $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(res){
           return res.data;
        });
    }

    return serverFactory;
})
.factory('LocalDbFactory', function() {
    var localDbFactory = {};

    localDbFactory.fetchJson = function() {
        // Return promise for JSON data here
    }  

    return localDbFactory;

})
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ServerFactory', 'LocalDbFactory', function($scope, ServerFactory, LocalDbFactory){

    var result;
    if (/* test if online */) {
        result = ServerFactory.fetchJson();
    } else {
        result = LocalDbFactory.fetchJson();
    }

    result.then(function(data) {
        $scope.elements = data;
    })

}])
```

Comment: Great! That's what I wanted to do. 
I wanted to return the 'data' from the petition, and not the whole promise. 

I didn't know how to do a 'return' within a .success().error() functions.

Question: When u write data.then(), you are refering to the previously var result, right? 
In order to work with the returned promise. I will test the code right away! =) Thank you!

Comment: Oops. I meant `result.then()`. We're just chaining of off the promise of either data from the server or local db. Also made a correction in the if statement. In the else block, `LocalDbFactory` should be making the call.

Comment: Yes, I gathered! haha Thanks you! =D

Comment: When I do the following:

`result.then(function(data) {
        $scope.elements = data;
        console.log($scope.elements;
    })`
what i get in this console.log is not 'data', it is the full promise object:

Object {data: Array(30), status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

I'm using the .then(data) clause, to manage asyncronous calls. That's the only remaining point missing.

Thank you very much, you helped a lot so far!

Comment: I answer myself:
I received a 'data' variable which had inside
data, status, config, statusText and headers.

I only had to do `$scope.elements = data.data;` to make it work.
It was not a Promise. =') Best regards!